# The role of internal voltage source resistance in pulsed operation

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, pulse, voltage-source

I have a question regarding the role of the internal voltage source resistance in pulsed vs DC operation. Here is a sketch of the situation I imagine:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6cc0l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**DC operation:**
The voltage at point at the voltage source output (**node 1**) will be determined by a voltage divider between the internal resistance of the voltage source and the transmission line, therefore: 
\$ V_1=\frac{R_2}{R_{source}+R_2}  V_{source}\$

**Pulsed operation:**
Assume that the voltage source launches a rectangular pulse of amplitude \$V_0\$ and duration \$\tau\$. Now, I assume that the resistor \$R_2\$ is a long transmission line, with a travelling time \$t\$ much longer than the pulse duration \$t >> \tau\$.

Also, it should be matched to the generator, such that no reflections occur at node 1.

**Question:** After the voltage pulse travelled through the source resistor \$R_{source}\$, will it be completely contained in \$R_2\$ and the voltage amplitude inside the line will be \$V_0\$ (and not a voltage divided value)?

Comment: Tidied up your Tex, $ needs a \ character to escape it on this site.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense - what is V0? How can a voltage pulse be "contained in R2"? What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 1):

The voltage at node 1 during the pulse will be V_0 / 2 (assuming transmission line impedance = Rsource). The input to the transmission line will continue to behave like a resistor until any reflection from the far end of the line reaches the start of the line again. If the line is terminated with the characteristic impedance then there will be no reflection and the input will continue to look resistive indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal resistors do not have memory, in pulsed operation you would get exactly the equation of DC operation. In this case exactly half of the input voltage at any time. Capacitors and Inductors (and now memristors) are the only circuit elements that can cause voltage to vary with time based on the signals past.

If your talking about PC board traces, then other rules apply. You have transmission line effects and parasitics. Transmission lines do have a memory, and can be modeled as a network of resistors, capacitors, and inductors.

If your talking about real resistors, each resistor has a small amount of inductance and capacitance that may need to be accounted for depending on the situation (usually high speed).

Comment: In the OP's question, the load resistor was replaced with a transmission line for the pulsed case.